# SQL Server uses only PRIMARY partition by default

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

My database has 2 partitions files: PRIMARY, DATABASE_ARCHIVED. A lot of tables have a column "archived". When archived is 1 row is in the DATABASE_ARCHIVED partition. When archived is 0 row is in the PRIMARY partition.

To improve performance I started to modify requests in the application by adding `archive=0` in `WHERE` and `JOIN`.

```
select *
from myTable1 t1 
join myTable2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.t1id 
and t2.archive=0  
where t1.archive=0
```

But there are a lot of requests, and I might make mistake when typing and won't be able to test everything.

Is there a way to force all requests on the PRIMARY partition and use the ARCHIVED partition on demand? In the application there is a checkbox to see archived data or not.

Not checked : look for data in PRIMARY ONLY, checked : look in both partition.

Can I do this?

Comment: how much data are you talking about? Thousands of rows or tens of millions? how big is the db? a few Gb? or hundreds?

Comment: can you clarify: do you have 1 table that is partitioned? or do you have 2 tables?

Comment: I have 12 tables partitionned, bigest table are up to 3-4 milion of row (17 years of production), total Db is 10Go.

Comment: sql server should be able to handle 3-4 million rows easily provided you maintain your indexes and statistics and tune your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are talking about partitioned tables, sql uses the where clause to filter rows. if your query doesn't have the where clause it will return all rows.
if you can't test your changes you probably shouldn't be making them.

Comment: this probably what will happend, change only request where there is some obvious slowness. I was hopping that I could do it with something else than where clause.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, even you have 2 database files to take advantage from partitioning you must create partitions (this feature is available only in `Eneterprise Edition` of SQL Server). Each partition will be in different file. No Archived will be in `PRIMARY` file. Others will be in `DATABASE_ARCHIVED`. The process is automatic, so there is no need to change any SQL queries.

So if configured properly the data will be automatically set in propper place.

Take into account that the filed for partitioning must be clustered index.

As other recommendation - you can set filegroup with archived data to be `read-only`. this will speed-up the queries. The problem is that you have to set procedure that periodically archives data - set partition to `write`, updates records for archiving and sets file to `read-only` again.

Take into acoount that when you have partitoning with `read-only file group` the backup procedure will be complex.

Comment: thanks, I (my client) has an enterprise edition (me a developper edition). My partitioning is working well. I have a stored procedure that run daily and change archive from 0 to 1. My problem is that I don't want to modify my queries to add where clause. In the execution plan of all my queries I want that the <PartitionsAccessed PartitionCount="1"> is always 1 and not 2. thanks for the read only tips !

Comment: @jpprade If you don't want to change your queries then stop using multiple partitions in the active table. It will be a bit more work but you can keep active data in one table and archived data in a separate table. For queries that *do* need to access both partitions, use a union (or create a view that unions them). From the sounds of it, you don't have any queries that go against the archived data, so why you want to keep both sets of data in the same table is beyond me.

Comment: Sorry @jpprade, but I dont understand. I think that you make mystake, or I don't understand what you need (sorry for my English I have working knowledge). Why you need to modify queries. If before partitioning you want ot extract all data you I suppose that you use: `select * from mytable`. After the partitoning it is the same. The only difference (if the partitioning is correctly created) is that the archived data is stored in `DATABASE_ARCHIVED` filegroup.
You actually make queries slower, because you add extra joins and where clauses in for the same table!

Comment: Maybe I am making a mistake, using partionning is not coming from me so maybe this solution is not optimal. The goal is to make the application faster : select queries look for less row. Maybe I have 2M "orders" in database, and 1.5M are archived. Then I want to see all the Order placed by a customer A, but I care only for the recent one. I want to display the order quickly and looking for 500k row should be faster than in 2M rows. queries is `select * from orders where archive=0 and customer=A`, is this a good solution ?

Comment: For sure @jpprade. It depends if you need to query often old and new data at the same time. In any case partitioning in my point add complexity. I use such kind of solution with `read-only` archived file group. But I have a procedure that each month add data to archive by chaning partitioning function boundaries. In your case it is much simpler. But may be the solution that Aaron Bertrand supposes is better. Just move old data to separate tables and if you need to query both use `UNION`.

Comment: Just a remark, @jpprade - when you move old data use insert into archived data and then delete with join - in this way you will be sure that you always delete only data that is copied to archived tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use views to expose your tables including the WHERE clause that filters the data according to your partition function.

For instance, if you have a table dbo.Orders, you could move it to a different schema (eg data) and have data.Orders as the table name. Then you could create a view named dbo.Orders to filter just the active data:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Orders 
AS 
SELECT SomeColumns
FROM data.Orders
WHERE archive = 0
```

This way, your application will access just the data without the archive flag set. If you want to access all the data, you can query data.Orders.

That said, you will have to test thoroughly the whole workload against this solution (some code may fail if it expects a table and finds a view instead, performance might be worse etc...).

Generally speaking, partitioning is **not** a performance feature: it is meant to be a manageability feature that **may** provide performance improvements as a positive side effect.